# Make a fixed panel to push the content instead of overlap

Tags: css

It needs to push up the existing content up, and make it overflow to make room for the bottom panel. I don't want the bottom panel to overlap anything on the page but thats what is happening. setting the bottom padding didn't help either.

http://jsfiddle.net/vwam5hvm/1/

```
#panel {
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    z-index:500;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this so that the existing content will be pushed up to make room for the bottom panel?

Comment: Where's `position: relative`?

Comment: @ochi it needs to push up the existing content up, and make it overflow to make room for the bottom panel. I don't want the bottom panel to overlap anything on the page.

Comment: is the panel to be fixed at the bottom and scroll out of sight when the content is large enough?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, if you have `padding-bottom` for body, it gets pushed up.

```css
#panel {
  bottom:0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index:500;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

body {
  padding-bottom: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div id='panel'>Hi Hello</div>
<pre>
    asd
    asfd
    
    
    asdf
    
    
    asdf
    
    
    
    
    asdf
    
    
    
    asdf
    
    
    
    
    asdf
    
    
    
    asdf
    
    
    asdf
    
    
    asdf
    
    
    asdf
    
    
    asdfsdaf
    
    
    
    sadf
    
    
    asdf
    
    
    
    asdf
    
    
    
    asdf
    
    
    
    sadf
    
    
    dsfsadf
    
    
    asddfasdf
    
    
    asdfasf
    
    asdfsdaf
</pre>
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working because it still ends up overalpping

Answer (score 1):

Set some `padding-bottom` value on the `<body>`, make the value the same height as the fixed element. You could use viewport units `vh` instead of percentage `%`, because a percentage `padding`/`margin` always relative to the width of the containing block, not the height.

```
body {
    padding-bottom: 25vh;
}
#panel {
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%; /*or 25vh*/
    z-index: 500;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffb7vrh2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#panel {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 98px;
    z-index: 500;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

pre {
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 98px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

This should give you the results. Hope this helped!